# Nested Counter for json data

Tags: python, json, datetime

I have a JSON data as:

```
{
    "persons": [
        {
            "city": "Seattle", 
            "name": "Brian"
            "dob" : "19-03-1980"
        }, 
        {
            "city": "Amsterdam", 
            "name": "David"
            "dob" : "19-09-1979"
        } 
       {
            "city": "London", 
            "name": "Joe"
            "dob" : "19-01-1980"
        }
        {
            "city": "Kathmandu", 
            "name": "Brian"
            "dob" : "19-03-1980"
        }
   ]
}
```

How can I count the individual elements, like, number of person born in Jan-Dec (0 if none were born) and born in given year using python in one single iteration. Also the number of unique names registered in each month
Like:

```
1980 :3
--Jan:1
--Mar:2
1979 :1
--Sep:1
```

Names:

```
Mar 1980: 1 #Brian is same for both cities 
Jan 1980: 1
Sep 1979: 1
```

counters_mon is the counter that has values for specific months of year

```
for k_mon,v_mon in counters_mon.items():
    print('{}={}'.format(k_mon,v_mon))
```

But I want details too to be printed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: For one, your json isn't valid (http://jsonlint.com/) and since you're able to call `counters_mon.items()`, you're probably working with dictionaries.

Comment: Right, first I extracted the values and added them in a list, and then performed actions on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json    

f = open('/path/to/your/json', 'r')
persons = json.load(f)
years_months = {}
years_months_names = {}

for person in persons['persons']:
    year = person['dob'][-4:]
    month = person['dob'][3:5]
    month_year = month + ' ' + year
    name = person['name']

    if year not in years_months.keys():
        years_months[year] = { 'count': 1, 'months' : {} }
        if month not in years_months[year]['months'].keys():
            years_months[year]['months'][month] = 1
        else:
            years_months[year]['months'][month] += 1
    else:
        years_months[year]['count'] += 1
        if month not in years_months[year]['months'].keys():
            years_months[year]['months'][month] = 1
        else:
            years_months[year]['months'][month] += 1

    if month_year not in years_months_names.keys():
        years_months_names[month_year] = set([name])
    else:
        years_months_names[month_year].add(name)

for k, v in years_months.items():
    print(k + ': ' + str(v['count']))
    for month, count in v['months'].items():
        print("-- " + str(month) + ": " + str(count))
for k, v in years_months_names.items():
    print(k + ": " + str(len(v)))
```

I'm assuming that you have the path to your json. I also tested my answer on the JSON that you've posted, and be careful to make sure that your JSON is structured correctly.

Comment: ~ Thanks for the answer, I shall give a try from the office system, and get back if there is something.

Comment: ~  Accepted the answer, but it is not showing the count of September in 1979 and gives March count as 1 but its actually 2 for 1980.

Comment: Check how your JSON is structured. I just tested it again with the code above and the output is correct. I'm also running Python 3.

Comment: It will also show the month number and not the month name.

Comment: 1979: 1
1980: 3
-- 03: 1
-- 01: 1
03 1980: 1
09 1979: 1
01 1980: 1

This is the output I am getting...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to  format it in the comment.

Comment: I modified my answer. Need to check the nested `if/else` condition twice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for using defaultdicts (https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
data   # assume you have your data in a var called data

from collections import defaultdict
from calendar import month_abbr

# slightly strange construction here but we want a 2 levels of defaultdict followed by lists
aggregate = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(list))

# then the population is super simple - you'll end up with something like
# aggregate[year][month] = [name1, name2]
for person in data['persons']:
    day, month, year = map(int, person['dob'].split('-'))
    aggregate[year][month].append(person['name'])


# I'm sorting in chronological order for printing
for year, months in sorted(aggregate.items()):
    print('{}: {}'.format(year, sum(len(names) for names in months.values())))
    for month, names in sorted(months.items()):
        print('--{}: {}'.format(month_abbr[month], len(names)))

for year, months in sorted(aggregate.items()):
    for month, names in sorted(months.items()):
        print('{} {}: {}'.format(month_abbr[month], year, len(set(names))))
```

Depending on how the data was going to be used I'd actually consider not having the complex nesting in the aggregation and instead opt for something like `aggregate[(year, month)] = [name1, name2,...]`. I find that the more nested my data, the more confusing it is to work with.

EDIT Alternatively you can create several structures on the first pass so the printing step is simplified. Again, I'm using `defaultdict` to clean up all the provisioning.

```
agg_years = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(int))   # [year][month] = counter
agg_years_total = defaultdict(int)   # [year] = counter
agg_months_names = defaultdict(set)   # [(year, month)] = set(name1, name2...)

for person in data['persons']:
    day, month, year = map(int, person['dob'].split('-'))

    agg_years[year][month] += 1
    agg_years_total[year] += 1
    agg_months_names[(year, month)].add(person['name'])


for year, months in sorted(agg_years.items()):
    print('{}: {}'.format(year, agg_years_total[year]))
    for month, quant in sorted(months.items()):
        print('--{}: {}'.format(month_abbr[month], quant))

for (year, month), names in sorted(agg_months_names.items()):
    print('{} {}: {}'.format(month_abbr[month], year, len(names)))
```